# How to redirect with a get parameter in django view?

Tags: django, redirect, parameters, get

I want to redirect with a GET parameter in django view. I want to use GET parameter for some reasons, not url parameter.

```
def product_new(request):
    group = request.GET.get('group')
    if group == None:
        product = Product.objects.create()
        return redirect('cms:product_list_edit')
    else:
        product = Product.objects.create(group=group)
        rreturn redirect('cms:product_list_edit') # I want to redirect this url with GET parameter.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Django has no tooling to add querystrings to an URL, but that is not per se a problem, since we can make our own function, for example:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect

def redirect_qd(viewname, *args, qd=None, **kwargs):
    rev = reverse(viewname, *args, **kwargs)
    if qd:
        rev = '{}?{}'.format(rev, qd.urlencode())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(rev)
```

Encoding the values is important. Imagine that your `group` has as value `foo&bar=3`. If you do *not* encode this properly, then this means that your querystring will later be parsed as two parameters: `group` and `bar` with `group` being `foo` and `bar` being `3`. This is thus not what you intended. By using the `urlencode`, it will result in `'group=foo%26bar%3D3'`, which thus is the intended value.

and then we can use this function like:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict

def product_new(request):
    group = request.GET.get('group')
    if group == None:
        product = Product.objects.create()
        return redirect('cms:product_list_edit')
    else:
        product = Product.objects.create(group=group)
        qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        qd.update(group=group)
        return redirect_qd('cms:product_list_edit', qd=qd)
```

If you simply want to pass the entire querystring, you can thus call it with `redirect_qd('myview', request.GET)`.

Answer (score 3):

for python3 and above:

```
def redirect_with_params(viewname, **kwargs):
    """
    Redirect a view with params
    """
    rev = reverse(viewname)

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(kwargs)
    if params:
        rev = '{}?{}'.format(rev, params)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(rev)
```

use:

```
redirect_with_params('main-domain:index', param1='value1', param2='value2')
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer exactly what I wanted.

```
def product_new(request):
    group = request.GET.get('group')
    if group == None:
        product = Product.objects.create()
        return redirect('cms:product_list_edit')
    else:
        product = Product.objects.create(group=group)
        response = redirect('cms:product_list_edit')
        response['Location'] += '?group=' + group
        return response
```

Comment: Please don't do that. If `group` contains for example an `&`, you will break the encoding. You need to properly escape the values.

Comment: The group will never contain `&`. Thank you!